# ARC Semantic Issue with simple protocol example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have just been trying something out with a quick test and I have a question, in the following code:

```
@protocol stuffieProtocol <NSObject>
@required 
-(void)favouiteBiscuit;
@end
```

.

```
// DOG & TED ARE IDENTICAL, THEY JUST LIKE DIFFERENT BISCUITS
@interface Dog : NSObject <stuffieProtocol>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation Dog

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithName:@"Unknown"];
}

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)whoAreYou {
    NSLog(@"MY NAME IS: %@ I AM A: %@", [self name], [self class]);
}
- (void)favouiteBiscuit {
    NSLog(@"FAVOURITE BISCUIT IS: Costa Jam Biscuit");
}
@end
```

.

```
Dog *stuffie_001 = [[Dog alloc] initWithName:@"Dog Armstrong"];
Ted *stuffie_002 = [[Ted alloc] initWithName:@"Teddy Sullivan"];

NSArray *stuffieArray = @[stuffie_001, stuffie_002];
for(id<stuffieProtocol> eachObject in stuffieArray) {
    [eachObject whoAreYou]; // << ERROR
    [eachObject favouiteBiscuit];
}
```

My question is I am getting an error `"ARC Semantic Issue: No known instance method for selector 'whoAreYou'"`

If I prefix `[eachObject whoAreYou];` with `[(Dog *)eachObject whoAreYou];` then this works for all the iterations of the loop, but that just feels wrong as the all the objects in the array are not of type `Dog`.

What should I be prefixing this with to be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
-(void) whoAreYou;
```

to your protocol. Then the compiler knows that `eachObject` in the loop responds to that method.

Comment: Thank you, interestingly enough it also works if you just declare the fast enumerator as "id" rather than "id <stuffieProtocol>"

Comment: Yes, because you can send any message to `id`. But then it may abort at runtime if the object does not respond to that selector. The compiler will not warn you. So either a protocol or a common superclass is the right thing to do.

Comment: So adding "id <stuffieProtocol>" essentially highlights a possible runtime problem at compile time, then using "respondsToSelector:" to determine if eachObject responds to the appropriate selector. It just seems a little strange as using just "id" and preforming "respondsToSelector:" leaves you in the same situation if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Actually in this particular case (getting objects from a collection) the compiler is not going to warn you of incorrect objects anyway. Just because you set it up as `for (id<SomeProtocol> obj in objects)` doesn't mean that the object's in the collection do in fact conform to `SomeProtocol`, so you still need to be aware of what is actually in the collection when coding or if you are not sure what's in the collection then use `respondsToSelector:`. The main gain of giving the right type here would be to help the compiler with autocompletion and allow dot notation.

Comment: @Paul.s: Good point. I missed that aspect in my answer/comment.

Answer (score 2):

well, you declare eachObject as an ID

that's mean that the compiler doesn't know what kind of object it is

it just know that it implements the protocol stuffieProtocol, so surely it can respond to method:  favouiteBiscuit

but it doesn't know if it can respond to method whoAreYou

you can do many thing to avoid this

the easiest is:

you could ask if eachObject can perform the selector whoAreYou, and in this case you perform that selector

```
if ([eachObject respondsToSelector:@selector(whoAreYou) ]) {
    [eachObject performSelector:@selector(whoAreYou) ];
}
```

this way the compiler avoid to control if eachObject implement the method whoAreYou

it will be done at runtime, so if there a method whoAreYou in eachObject, then ok, it will be called

Another way could be to make a common superclass for both ted and dog

(e.g.
 `SuperClassOfTedAndDog <stuffieProtocol`> 
)

and declare method whoAreYou in that superclass, then in your for loop use that superclass instead of ID:

```
for(SuperClassOfTedAndDog* eachObject in stuffieArray) {
    [eachObject whoAreYou]; 
    [eachObject favouiteBiscuit];
}
```